# Sending a string encoded as Byte array via tcpListener, new string length same like buffer size

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I am in need of creating a small application which sends text chucks. So I created a server using tcpListener. On my client I use tcpClient.

Now my problem:

```
data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test"); //length of "test" is 4.
```

now I am sending this byte array to my server application. There I am creating a buffer array with a size of 320000 bytes. (The size really doesn't matter here)

```
byte[] message = new byte[320000];
bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 320000);
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
string request = encoder.GetString (message);
```

And here is my problem now, the resulting request string has a length of 320000. Same size as my byte array. I do understand why it is like that, but what could I do to reduce the size back to it's original? Right now I use a RegEx to remove all chars that would never occur in my strings that I will send... but there must be a proper way of doing so...

Any help will be appreciated :)

Pat.

Comment: TCP is represented as a stream of bytes. That's it. There's no 1-1 correspondence between calls to `Read()` and calls to `Write()` on that stream. If you need to be able to break the stream of bytes apart into messages, it's *your* responsibility (unless you pick a higher level abstraction) to provide for yourself a means to split those messages apart. E.g. by prefixing the data with a length, or using delimiters, etc.

Comment: I guess I will also implement this. When I send the string and the connection drops, I assume some exception will be thrown, but with this I can really make sure I process only when the string has been transferred correctly. Thanks.

Comment: yes, you'd have started noticing this issue as soon as your client sent two messages and you noticed that both of them arrived in a single `Read()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
string request = encoder.GetString(message);
```

to

```
string request = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
```

Comment: Thank you Quinton, I have no idea why I didn't see this.

I am troubling myself with this for 3 days now!

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to use some identifier that will never appear anywhere else in your string to indicate the end of it.

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test+++++++");
```

Anything will work, and when you find this sequence you (string.indexof("+++++++")) just return a substring of the final result.

Comment: Quinton Bernhardt answer is the better way, i wasn't aware of the overload on that method.